# Confirm vs Throw

Tags: programming, assertion

Version 12.2 brought us [`Confirm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Confirm.html) and [`Enclose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Enclose.html). What's the point? Is it just that it's a slightly more convenient syntax than [`Throw`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) and [`Catch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html) with a conditional?

I can see where `Confirm` beats [`Assert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assert.html): you don't need to `On[Assert]` first, and also `Confirm` is catchable.

Comment: `Confirm` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so you can construct more fine-grained responses to what should happen when e.g. messages are created. I think the "mountainElevation" example in the Applications section of the `Confirm` documentation could not have been done (readably) with `Throw` and `Catch`.
Probably the idea was to create a more fine-tunable version of `Catch` and `Throw`, but I don't really know, since I don't work for WRI ...

Comment: It really deserves a "Background & Context" section in the docs. One difference is that `Confirm` throws a failure to an enclosing `Enclose` (bad name?) only if the expression evaluates to one of certain common forms of failure; otherwise, execution continues. The first example in "Applications" @Rolf points out shows how that might be syntactically convenient. It is perhaps no more than syntactic sugar for common `Catch/Throw` failure conditions.

Comment: One of the major differences is that `Enclose @ expr` scopes lexically for inner `Confirm`s (making these functions very predictable), while `Catch @ expr` scopes dynamically for inner `Throw`s. The dynamical scoping of single argument `Throw`/`Catch` is often very undesirable and Leonid takes every opportunity to point out that it's a defect of the language that they can completely break evaluation control because of that. In addition, `ConfirmBy` and `ConfrimMatch` etc. are just really nice syntactically.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I think that exceptions inherently scope dynamically to be useful, they are all about bubbling up through call stack until the proper handler is reached. If they would scope lexically, then this would just be a somewhat less local form of `Return`, similar in spirit to two-argument `Return`. What I have been criticizing are `Catch` and `Throw` without a tag, since then there is no way to be selective, and one can catch something that was intended to be caught  higher up in the call stack. This would be like e.g.  throwing `Exception` in Java, rather than its more specific subclass.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Sure, I probably didn't explain that very well in all the haste. I just wanted to convey that single-argument `Catch` and `Throw` are bad because of the dynamic scoping, while for the lexically scoped `Enclose`/`Confim` it's not a problem to not have tags. And since most people are lazy and use single-argument forms, `Enclose`/`Confirm` is a useful addition.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yeah, I get your point. I just wanted to point out that dynamic scoping is inherent in exceptions, so if we are willing to use them, we should accept that. Of course I agree that in all cases where the lexical scope can be used, it is safer. What makes single-arg `Catch` and `Throw` dangerous compared to their 2 or 3 arg counterparts is IMO not so much the dynamic nature (which they all share), but the fact that they can't be nested / re-entrant, so to speak. Which of course matters for dynamic scope, because in general you can't control the full evaluation stack.

Comment: I propose @SjoerdSmit write up a summary of the commentary as a response. Or anyone else who might feel so inclined.

Comment: This opens a namespace under the tag ConfirmationFailed in the [`Interpreter`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html?q=Interpreter) set included in Mathematica. The new built-ins offer a rich set of issues following the documentation pages. Since `Catch/Throw` are not interpreted it is hard to compare. It transfers the concepts of the flow management of `Catch/Throw` to the `Interpreter`. It requires a proper concept of tagging and offers individualization by associations. It is possible to integrate the `Interpreter` into usual built-ins as the main advantage. ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Confirm` and `Enclose` are higher-level constructs meant to provide a convenient (and readable) notation for recovering from expected but somewhat unusual conditions involving program data or state.  They happen to be built upon the lower-level `Throw`/`Catch` mechanism, but part of the point of their introduction is to hide such implementation details from the user.

`Throw` is a very low-level abstraction, akin to a *goto* statement.  In itself, it does not offer someone reading the code many clues as to its purpose.  By contrast, the various `Confirm` functions are meant to indicate to the reader that there are recovery strategies in place for:

- unusual data (`Confirm`, `ConfirmBy` and `ConfirmMatch`)
- unusual program state (`ConfirmAssert`)
- unusual warning messages (`ConfirmQuiet`)

The `Confirm` family join a growing list of non-local return features within *Mathematica*.  In principle, all such constructs could be implemented using only `Throw`, `Catch` and `CheckAll`.  Nevertheless, there are many features for specific purposes and with specific names.  Consider:

| Signaller | Handler | Handler Scope | Unwinding Continues | Error If Unhandled | Primary Use |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Throw` | `Catch` | dynamic | if tag unmatched | yes | general-purpose non-local exit facility |
| `Abort` | `CheckAbort` | dynamic | no | yes | error-handling |
| `Message` | `Check` | dynamic | if messages unmatched | no | warning-handling |
| `Assert` | `$AssertFunction` | dynamic | n/a | no | checking programming preconditions |
| `Confirm` `ConfirmBy` `ConfirmMatch` | `Enclose` | lexical or dynamic | if tag unmatched | yes | recovering from unusual data |
| `ConfirmAssert` | `Enclose` | lexical or dynamic | if tag unmatched | yes | recovering from unusual program state |
| `ConfirmQuiet` | `Enclose` | lexical or dynamic | if tag unmatched | yes | recovering from warnings |
| *any* | `WithCleanup` | dynamic | yes | depends upon signal | resource disposal |
| *any* | `` Internal` WithLocalSettings `` | dynamic | yes | depends upon signal | resource disposal |
| *any* | `CheckAll` | dynamic | no | depends upon signal | backstopping exits |

Many of these names and functions have arisen due to history.  `Enclose` and `WithCleanup` may represent a move by WRI to unify the handling patterns for expected but unusual program conditions.  It might explain why there is no `ConfirmNoAbort` -- `Abort` can be reserved for truly unexpected program errors.

Some observations:

- `Throw`/`Catch` are similar to the like-named symbols in Lisp, as well as *longjmp/setjmp* from C.
- `Abort`/`CheckAbort` are similar to *throw/try-catch* in C++, Java and C#... except that with `CheckAbort` it can be difficult (or impossible) to identify the triggering signal using just `$MessageList`.  So `Throw`/`Catch` are often used instead for error-handling.
- `ConfirmAssert` and `Assert` are similar but perhaps the former should now be used for handling expected program conditions and the latter reserved for forensics during debugging sessions.
- `ConfirmQuiet` is much like `Check` except that it integrates with `Enclose`.
- `CheckAll` and `` Internal`WithLocalSettings `` are [undocumented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208942/142).  But the recently introduced experimental symbol [WithCleanup](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WithCleanup.html) covers most of the functionality provided by the latter.  `WithCleanup` is similar to *unwind-protect* in Lisp and *try-finally* in Java and C#.  `CheckAll` is similar to a handler for type *t* in Lisp or *try-catch(Throwable)* in Java.
- As of V12.2, the lexical forms of `Confirm` are simulated by dynamic `Throw`/`Catch` using private tags and some heuristic checks in `Enclose`.  The abstraction is a bit leaky but likely not to the point of real harm... for fun try `Enclose[Confirm[SymbolName@#]]&[Confirm]` (working with held code is really hard in WL).

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete overview. It is very helpful.

Comment: +1, very nice answer. I am happy I have not tried to answer myself, it would've likely been a half-hearted and / or needlessly bloated attempt compared to this one.